# Quantile Regression Library in Java or Scala

Tags: java, machine-learning

I need quantile regression library in java or scala. I have searched online and couldn't find any.

Do anyone know if such library exists or I'll need to write my own implementation?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen it among Java packages. Go to this URL https://jwork.org/dmelt/search/ This searches for Java packages inside DataMelt software.